# How to validate classes' immutability in SonarQube?

Tags: java, sonarqube, immutability, sonarqube-scan

I'm about to introduce DI into my project but for this, I need to be sure that none of the classes intended to be Singleton store a state. For this matter, I think about performing a simple validation and assure all such classes are immutable.

The first thing that has come to my mind was SonarQube and I discovered such a rule:
https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1165

Does anybody know how to extend this rule from exceptions to simple classes and trigger an immutability check by a custom annotation?

Please let me know if you see any disadvantages in my approach or know links with useful information.

Comment: Consider using `final` on your singleton references, so that the compiler can do some work for you. For classes that do not cause delays due to initialization consider using `new`. Even better, use factories.

Comment: Yes, and I want to introduce a validation processor to assure the immutability